# How to show Infragistics's UltraDesktopAlert from thread

Tags: c#, infragistics, multithreading

i am facing problem from many days. I have a thread listening for notificaitons from other system. whenever i receive a notification over socket i want to display it in Alert window using Infragistics's UltraDesktopAlert control. there is no winform in this class library.

please tell me how to display it using a thread. a sample is here

```
  void tcpServerListenter_OnCommReceive(object sender, CommEventArgs e)
        {
            string xmlString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])e.data);
            try
            {
                XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
                var res = (from msg in xmlDoc.Descendants("consoleNotification")
                           select msg.Element("value").Value).FirstOrDefault();

                this.notificationMsg = res;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

// here Alert window is not displaying.
ultraDesktopAlert1.Show("Notification", this.notificationMsg);      
        }
```

but this code is not displaying alert window.

i checked the following link also
[How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

but problem is that i have no Winform in my class library. what i wants to display alert window whenever i receive notification on socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do safe cross threading since the ultraDesktopAlert1 Infragistics object was created by the main thread but being accessed on a different thread.

Check out this [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx) on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is save the UI thread's synchronization context and Send a lambda over to the UI thread...

On the UI Thread, when/before initiating your Async operation...

```
SynchronizationContext syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

Save this into the class that is doing the aSync work, then you want to Send your code to run on the saved synchronization context.

```
syncContext.Send((stateMsg) => ultraDesktopAlert1.Show("Notification", stateMsg), this.notificationMessage);
```

Note that if you need to retrieve the Current SynchronizationContext from the UI thread, you can't get the UI threads synchronization context from a non UI thread.